# correct method to create user in alpine docker container so that sudo works correctly

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

When attempting to execute `sudo` in a docker container using **alpine 3.8** I get the following output.

I am logged into the container using `docker exec -i -t MYIMAGE /bin/bash`

```
bash-4.4$ whoami
payara
bash-4.4$ sudo -s
bash-4.4$ whoami
payara
bash-4.4$ su root
su: incorrect password
bash-4.4$
```

My docker file contains the following user related commands to try and setup a user specifically for payara. I want sudo to work correctly though, if possible.

**DockerFile**

```
FROM "alpine:latest"

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV http_proxy 'http://u:p@160.48.234.129:80'
ENV https_proxy 'http://u:p@160.48.234.129:80'

RUN apk add --no-cache bash gawk sed grep bc coreutils git openssh-client libarchive libarchive-tools busybox-suid sudo            

RUN addgroup -S payara && adduser -S -G payara payara
RUN echo "payara ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# CHANGE TO PAYARA USER
USER payara

... rest of setup.
```

Comment: As a quick workaround you could connect to your container as root user:

`docker exec -u 0 -i -t MYIMAGE /bin/bash`.

The parameter `-u 0` means the id of the root user, which is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man sudo`:

```
 -s, --shell
             Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's password database entry.
```

You have neither `SHELL` variable set, nor correct (interactive) default shell set in `/etc/passwd` for user `payara`. This is because you are creating a system user (`-S`) - this user has a default shell `/bin/false` (which just exits with exit code `1` - you may check with `echo $?` after unsuccessfull `sudo -s`).

You may overcome this in different ways:

a) specify the `SHELL` variable:

```
bash-4.4$ SHELL=/bin/bash sudo -s
bed662af470d:~#
```

b) use `su`, which will use the default `root`'s shell:

```
bash-4.4$ sudo su -
bed662af470d:~#
```

c) just run the required privileged commands with `sudo` directly, without spawning an interactive shell.